# rails 5.1.6 mysql2 error while migrating db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When running `rake db:migrate`, I am running into this error

`NameError:uninitialized constant mysql2:: Client :: found_rows.`

Am using gem `mysql2` n xampp as a localhost

Comment: which version of `mysql` gem you are using

Comment: Iam using this version Gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.0'

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue, which is get resolved after updating `mysql2` gem to version `0.3.18`.

Comment: I also have Tried that and it didn't  work either. Same error re-occurred

Comment: Ganesh thank you, restarted the machine n bundle installed your gem version n it works. Thanks brother

Comment: Good to hear. That means it was most likely a version issue.

Comment: I got the same error, mysql2 version 0.5.0. It seems new mysql2 not define that constant FOUND_ROWS

Answer (score 0):

Causes a new problem. mysql2 binary will not work for anything above ruby 2.4  Still looking for a solution that will work to connect mysql database to app.